# Android button black color by default

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-button

Buttons I create programatically have very strange behaviour. In one project they are "normal gray" colored while in another they're black. I am using the same manifest in both projects.

My activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context="com.example.maris.caffeappapi.MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/buttonlayout"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Call Service"
        android:id="@+id/button1" />

    <TextView
        android:paddingTop="16px"
        android:id="@+id/jsonParsed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

And finally the code I use to create my buttons(inside onCreate method)

```
Button myButton = new Button(this.context);
myButton.setText(object.getString("name"));

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.buttonlayout);
LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

ll.addView(myButton, lp);
```

This is what I am getting on my first project,

[image: 1st project]

and this is what I'm getting on my second project,
[image: 2nd project]

Comment: Whats your theme (in styles.xml)?

Comment: <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">, same one in both of them